# Can http api or json api work with HAProxy setting?

Tags: json, jsp, http, tcp, haproxy

Can HTTP API or JSON API work with HAProxy settings? The configuration of the environment is as follows.

[image]

It was Tomcat & Apache & WAS all server installed. And the configuration of the haproxy setting is as follows.

global

```
log         127.0.0.1       local0
log         127.0.0.1       local1 notice
chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
maxconn     10000
user        haproxy
group       haproxy
daemon
stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats
```

defaults

```
    mode            tcp
    log             global
    option          tcplog
    option          dontlognull
    option          redispatch
    option          tcp-check
    tcp-check send GET\ /my/check/url\ HTTP/1.1\r\n
    tcp-check send Host:\ myhost\r\n
    tcp-check send Connection:\ close\r\n
    tcp-check send \r\n
    tcp-check expect string HTTP/1.1\ 200\ OK
    tcp-check expect ! string Error

    retries                 5
    timeout http-request    20s
    timeout queue           86400
    timeout connect         86400
    timeout client          86400
    timeout server          86400
    timeout http-keep-alive 30s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 10000


listen scaphaproxy 203.227.22.9:8080
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    log global

    #HTTP Chk Option
    option httpchk GET /
    option log-health-checks
    option dontlognull

    #Load Balancing
    balance     leastconn
    maxconn    10000
```

## server1

```
    server scapugs9201 203.227.22.64:9201
    server scapugs9202 203.227.22.64:9202
    server scapugs9203 203.227.22.64:9203
    server scapugs9204 203.227.22.64:9204
    server scapugs9205 203.227.22.64:9205
    server scapugs9206 203.227.22.64:9206
    server scapugs9207 203.227.22.64:9207
    server scapugs9208 203.227.22.64:9208
    server scapugs9209 203.227.22.64:9209
    server scapugs9210 203.227.22.64:9210

    server scapugs9211 203.227.22.64:9211
    server scapugs9212 203.227.22.64:9212
    server scapugs9213 203.227.22.64:9213
    server scapugs9214 203.227.22.64:9214
    server scapugs9215 203.227.22.64:9215
    server scapugs9216 203.227.22.64:9216
    server scapugs9217 203.227.22.64:9217
    server scapugs9218 203.227.22.64:9218
    server scapugs9219 203.227.22.64:9219
    server scapugs9220 203.227.22.64:9220

    server scapugs9221 203.227.22.64:9221
    server scapugs9222 203.227.22.64:9222
    server scapugs9223 203.227.22.64:9223
    server scapugs9224 203.227.22.64:9224
    server scapugs9225 203.227.22.64:9225
    server scapugs9226 203.227.22.64:9226
    server scapugs9227 203.227.22.64:9227
    server scapugs9228 203.227.22.64:9228
    server scapugs9229 203.227.22.64:9229
    server scapugs9230 203.227.22.64:9230

    server scapugs9231 203.227.22.64:9231
    server scapugs9232 203.227.22.64:9232
    server scapugs9233 203.227.22.64:9233
    server scapugs9234 203.227.22.64:9234
    server scapugs9235 203.227.22.64:9235
    server scapugs9236 203.227.22.64:9236
    server scapugs9237 203.227.22.64:9237
    server scapugs9238 203.227.22.64:9238
    server scapugs9239 203.227.22.64:9239
    server scapugs9240 203.227.22.64:9240

    server scapugs9241 203.227.22.64:9241
    server scapugs9242 203.227.22.64:9242
    server scapugs9243 203.227.22.64:9243
    server scapugs9244 203.227.22.64:9244
    server scapugs9245 203.227.22.64:9245
    server scapugs9246 203.227.22.64:9246
    server scapugs9247 203.227.22.64:9247
    server scapugs9248 203.227.22.64:9248
    server scapugs9249 203.227.22.64:9249
    server scapugs9250 203.227.22.64:9250

    server scapugs9251 203.227.22.64:9251
    server scapugs9252 203.227.22.64:9252
    server scapugs9253 203.227.22.64:9253
    server scapugs9254 203.227.22.64:9254
    server scapugs9255 203.227.22.64:9255
    server scapugs9256 203.227.22.64:9256
    server scapugs9257 203.227.22.64:9257
    server scapugs9258 203.227.22.64:9258
    server scapugs9259 203.227.22.64:9259
    server scapugs9260 203.227.22.64:9260

    server scapugs9261 203.227.22.64:9261
    server scapugs9262 203.227.22.64:9262
    server scapugs9263 203.227.22.64:9263
    server scapugs9264 203.227.22.64:9264
    server scapugs9265 203.227.22.64:9265
    server scapugs9266 203.227.22.64:9266
    server scapugs9267 203.227.22.64:9267
    server scapugs9268 203.227.22.64:9268
    server scapugs9269 203.227.22.64:9269
    server scapugs9270 203.227.22.64:9270

    server scapugs9271 203.227.22.64:9271
    server scapugs9272 203.227.22.64:9272
    server scapugs9273 203.227.22.64:9273
    server scapugs9274 203.227.22.64:9274
    server scapugs9275 203.227.22.64:9275
    server scapugs9276 203.227.22.64:9276
    server scapugs9277 203.227.22.64:9277
    server scapugs9278 203.227.22.64:9278
    server scapugs9279 203.227.22.64:9279
    server scapugs9280 203.227.22.64:9280

    server scapugs9281 203.227.22.64:9281
    server scapugs9282 203.227.22.64:9282
    server scapugs9283 203.227.22.64:9283
    server scapugs9284 203.227.22.64:9284
    server scapugs9285 203.227.22.64:9285
    server scapugs9286 203.227.22.64:9286
    server scapugs9287 203.227.22.64:9287
    server scapugs9288 203.227.22.64:9288
    server scapugs9289 203.227.22.64:9289
    server scapugs9290 203.227.22.64:9290

    server scapugs9291 203.227.22.64:9291
    server scapugs9292 203.227.22.64:9292
    server scapugs9293 203.227.22.64:9293
    server scapugs9294 203.227.22.64:9294
    server scapugs9295 203.227.22.64:9295
    server scapugs9296 203.227.22.64:9296
    server scapugs9297 203.227.22.64:9297
    server scapugs9298 203.227.22.64:9298
    server scapugs9299 203.227.22.64:9299
    server scapugs9300 203.227.22.64:9300
```

## server2

```
    server scapugs9101 203.227.22.65:9101
    server scapugs9102 203.227.22.65:9102
    server scapugs9103 203.227.22.65:9103
    server scapugs9104 203.227.22.65:9104
    server scapugs9105 203.227.22.65:9105
    server scapugs9106 203.227.22.65:9106
    server scapugs9107 203.227.22.65:9107
    server scapugs9108 203.227.22.65:9108
    server scapugs9109 203.227.22.65:9109
    server scapugs9110 203.227.22.65:9110

    server scapugs9111 203.227.22.65:9111
    server scapugs9112 203.227.22.65:9112
    server scapugs9113 203.227.22.65:9113   
    server scapugs9114 203.227.22.65:9114
    server scapugs9115 203.227.22.65:9115
    server scapugs9116 203.227.22.65:9116
    server scapugs9117 203.227.22.65:9117
    server scapugs9118 203.227.22.65:9118
    server scapugs9119 203.227.22.65:9119
    server scapugs9120 203.227.22.65:9120

    server scapugs9121 203.227.22.65:9121
    server scapugs9122 203.227.22.65:9122
    server scapugs9123 203.227.22.65:9123
    server scapugs9124 203.227.22.65:9124
    server scapugs9125 203.227.22.65:9125
    server scapugs9126 203.227.22.65:9126
    server scapugs9127 203.227.22.65:9127
    server scapugs9128 203.227.22.65:9128
    server scapugs9129 203.227.22.65:9129
    server scapugs9130 203.227.22.65:9130

    server scapugs9131 203.227.22.65:9131
    server scapugs9132 203.227.22.65:9132
    server scapugs9133 203.227.22.65:9133
    server scapugs9134 203.227.22.65:9134
    server scapugs9135 203.227.22.65:9135
    server scapugs9136 203.227.22.65:9136
    server scapugs9137 203.227.22.65:9137
    server scapugs9138 203.227.22.65:9138
    server scapugs9139 203.227.22.65:9139               
    server scapugs9140 203.227.22.65:9140

    server scapugs9141 203.227.22.65:9141
    server scapugs9142 203.227.22.65:9142   
    server scapugs9143 203.227.22.65:9143
    server scapugs9144 203.227.22.65:9144
    server scapugs9145 203.227.22.65:9145
    server scapugs9146 203.227.22.65:9146
    server scapugs9147 203.227.22.65:9147
    server scapugs9148 203.227.22.65:9148
    server scapugs9149 203.227.22.65:9149       
    server scapugs9150 203.227.22.65:9150

    server scapugs9151 203.227.22.65:9151
    server scapugs9152 203.227.22.65:9152
    server scapugs9153 203.227.22.65:9153
    server scapugs9154 203.227.22.65:9154
    server scapugs9155 203.227.22.65:9155
    server scapugs9156 203.227.22.65:9156
    server scapugs9157 203.227.22.65:9157
    server scapugs9158 203.227.22.65:9158
    server scapugs9159 203.227.22.65:9159
    server scapugs9160 203.227.22.65:9160

    server scapugs9161 203.227.22.65:9161
    server scapugs9162 203.227.22.65:9162
    server scapugs9163 203.227.22.65:9163
    server scapugs9164 203.227.22.65:9164
    server scapugs9165 203.227.22.65:9165
    server scapugs9166 203.227.22.65:9166
    server scapugs9167 203.227.22.65:9167
    server scapugs9168 203.227.22.65:9168
    server scapugs9169 203.227.22.65:9169       
    server scapugs9170 203.227.22.65:9170

    server scapugs9171 203.227.22.65:9171
    server scapugs9172 203.227.22.65:9172
    server scapugs9173 203.227.22.65:9173
    server scapugs9174 203.227.22.65:9174
    server scapugs9175 203.227.22.65:9175
    server scapugs9176 203.227.22.65:9176
    server scapugs9177 203.227.22.65:9177
    server scapugs9178 203.227.22.65:9178
    server scapugs9179 203.227.22.65:9179
    server scapugs9180 203.227.22.65:9180

    server scapugs9181 203.227.22.65:9181
    server scapugs9182 203.227.22.65:9182
    server scapugs9183 203.227.22.65:9183
    server scapugs9184 203.227.22.65:9184  
    server scapugs9185 203.227.22.65:9185
    server scapugs9186 203.227.22.65:9186
    server scapugs9187 203.227.22.65:9187
    server scapugs9188 203.227.22.65:9188
    server scapugs9189 203.227.22.65:9189
    server scapugs9190 203.227.22.65:9190

    server scapugs9191 203.227.22.65:9191
    server scapugs9192 203.227.22.65:9192
    server scapugs9193 203.227.22.65:9193
    server scapugs9194 203.227.22.65:9194  
    server scapugs9195 203.227.22.65:9195
    server scapugs9196 203.227.22.65:9196
    server scapugs9197 203.227.22.65:9197
    server scapugs9198 203.227.22.65:9198
    server scapugs9199 203.227.22.65:9199
    server scapugs9200 203.227.22.65:9200
```

All servers do socket communication and only haproxy mode tcp and LB is leastconn. I would like to send the HAProxy status information to the web page separately. To do this, you need to send HTTP API or JSON API on the web page to the proxy server.

Please let me know if there is a way. So, I need to connect 1000 ports to one server.

(ex: client ip <-> proxy ip:8080 <-> server ip:(1101 ~ 2101))
Is there a way to reduce this part?